# Keyboard randomly stops working. Switch to console mode and back fixes it

Tags: keyboard

AS the title says I'm on 10.04 and sometimes the keyboard will just plain stop working.  Mouse still works fine.  A quick `<Ctrl> + <Alt> + F4` then `<Ctrl> + <Alt> + F7` and the keyboard works again.

Is this a known issue? Am I just doing something dumb and not realizing it?

Thanks.

Comment: My 11.04 install suddenly started having the same issue. Same workaround helps. Anyone have an explanation or solution??

Answer (score 3):

Turns out for me that I had a stuck button on my mouse that kept bringing the help menu up.  When I switched mice the problem stopped.  I never noticed this with the mouse on osx since the button didn't map to anything.