# Keyboard stops working on a Dell Inspiron 7110

Tags: keyboard

Title says it all. Do note that the keyboard stops randomly, and i never had problems during the install or boot or such.

I wrote this w/ my on-screen keyboard. it has no function keys however, so the solution presented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95027/10-04-keyboard-randomly-stops-working-switch-to-console-mode-and-back-fixes-it) wouldn't be applicable.

I also naturally wouldn't want to have to relog every time this happens.

I can access my console fine w/ my on-screen keybd, so terminal commands i can do.

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 7110

Comment: I had a similar problem. I was unable to click to. I tried different buttons on the keyboard: after pressing `F11`  I tried to type and everything was fine. However I use a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

When it happens to me I usually click on the touchpad (**not the mouse**) and it resumes working.

Bad bug, btw, Ubuntu's getting worse and worse.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my keyboard. What helped (I'm not quite sure about names 'cause I have a russian localization):
System settings > Special needs (icon of a white man in blue circle) > Input > "Slow" keys => disable. 
Everything started working immediately.

Sorry for bad English, not a native speaker:)